# Parent index.html with iframe link to server with new index.html

Tags: html, iframe, mobile

FULL PARENT INDEX:

```
    <html><head><title>www.homepageurl.com</title></head><frameset BORDER='0' frameborder='0' framespacing='0' rows='100%,*'>
<frame name='target'src='http://members.?????'>
<noframes>  <body BGCOLOR='#FFFFFF'>
This page requires that your browser supports frames.
<BR>You can access the page without frames with this <a href='http://members.??????/'>link</A>.
</body></noframes></frameset></html>
```

---

Hey there,

Ive made a relaunch on a Website. The old Website was about 16 years old. I got access to the linked server as shown above. The problem is, the site doesn´t work on mobile phones. On my Testserver it works. And if i put the linked url (member.???) in my browser it also works. So, i think the problem is that link, in that parent index.

So my Question. Is it possible to put a code in the head of the child index to prevent that iframe, because thats the problem i think i have in the moment. Thx for your answers...

Comment: (function(window) {
  if (window.location !== window.top.location) {
    window.top.location = window.location;
  }
})(this);

</script>

Comment: ive tried this and works but now it display no more the right URL ... now the site member.???? ....

Answer (score 0):

Use `<iframe>` instead of `<frame>` (inside the `body` of your page, and no framesets)

Comment: Please give me a hint .. or an excample. can´t change the main index.html.